XNAT authentication failure
I'm trying to use the XNAT API to download MRI scans from XNAT via the command line, but I'm getting this error when trying to log in:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../xnat_download.py", line 21, in <module>
    xnat_session = xnat.connect(XNAT_URL, user=username, password=password)
  File ".../miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xnat/__init__.py", line 628, in connect
    jsession_token = _create_jsession(requests_session,
  File ".../miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xnat/__init__.py", line 335, in _create_jsession
    raise exceptions.XNATLoginFailedError('Encountered a problem logging in: {}'.format(message))
xnat.exceptions.XNATLoginFailedError: Encountered a problem logging in: Authentication failed.

Here's the code:
import getpass
import os
import requests
import urllib.request
import xnat
import json

# Set the XNAT server URL and the project ID
XNAT_URL = '...'
PROJECT_ID = '...'

# Set the directory where the imaging data will be downloaded
DATA_DIR = '...'

# Prompt the user for their username and password
username = input('Enter your XNAT username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Enter your XNAT password: ')

# Connect to the XNAT server using the xnatpy library
xnat_session = xnat.connect(XNAT_URL, user=username, password=password)

# Check if the connection was successful
if xnat_session:
    print('Authentication successful')
    ...
else:
    print('Authentication failed')

I'm sure the password is correct and I also know the code used to work for my colleague, so I'm not sure how to figure out what is going on. Any ideas are appreciated!
